# Dojo can't make a CORS request. jQuery can

Tags: ajax, dojo, xmlhttprequest, cors

I've setup a dojo module to handle my communication:

```
define(["dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/json"],
  function(xhr, JSON) {

  return {
    getJson: function(url) {
      return xhr.get(url, {handleAs:'json', headers: {"X-Requested-With": ""}});
    },
    postJson: function(url, postData) {
      return xhr(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        handleAs: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        headers: {"X-Requested-With": "", "Content-Type":"application/json"}
      })
    },
    getSecure: function(url, token) {
      return xhr.get(url, {handleAs:'json', headers: {"X-AUTH": token, "X-Requested-With": "", "Content-Type":"application/json" }});
    },
    postSecure: function(url, postData, token) {
      return xhr(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        handleAs: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        headers: {"X-Requested-With": "", "Content-Type":"application/json", "X-AUTH": token}
      });
    }
  };

});
```

While sending a request, OPTIONS fails almost immediately. I tried the request in Postman just to make sure the API was alive and well. Then I got a wild hair and built a quick test in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://someurl.url/auth/get_token',
  type: 'post',
  data: JSON.stringify({username:"user", password:"pass"}),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json' ,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: false
  },
  success: function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://someurl.url/api/service/' + json.results.somevalue,
      type: 'GET',
      headers: { 'X-AUTH': json.results.token },
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json' ,
      success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);

      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
      }


    });

  },
  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("error :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
  }
```

That works just fine. I know that Dojo was having problems a year or so ago with sending the 'X-Requested-width' header, but I've nulled that out and it's not attempting to send it. I'm pulling my hair out as I really don't want to include jQuery as a dependency to my app just for making web requests. Dojo SHOULD be able to do this. Any Dojo people out there have any idea how to make this work?

Comment: The issue is likely with your server.  Show us the request headers, along with the response headers from your server from a failing attempt.

Comment: The jquery request: http://imgur.com/RgV8ZBc and the dojo request: http://imgur.com/5o1sdQC I sincerely apologize for the images, I don't have access to the server. All I can really show is how the request works in jquery and the response from the server in devtools.

Comment: You don't need access to the server to provide the actual response headers.  You can insert a transparent proxy between your client and the server to accurately record these.  You can't trust the browser to report headers correctly, or at all for a CORS request with a response that doesn't properly acknowledge the CORS request.  With only the request headers and only provisional headers for the preflight sent with Dojo in the mix, it's hard to say why the request is failing.  I'm guessing that all of this will be quite clear once you look at the actual request and response headers.

Comment: Wireshark is  probably a bit too low-level if you are only interested in HTTP traffic.  I'd suggest using something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) instead.  I'm out of here for the night.  Just in case you get to post this data, I'll check back in tomorrow and take a look in the event someone else hasn't swooped in.

Comment: I appreciate all the help, in the end it turned out to be a malformed URL. Charles DID point it out right off the bat as I noticed another folder of requests being created.

Comment: And how was this malformed URL created?  How does this relate to the original question (dojo vs jquery) at all?

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question. So it's not a Dojo problem at all. Should this question be deleted?

Answer (score 3):

Empty string is not the same thing as null. You need to set X-Requested-With to `null`, not `""`, to avoid a preflight request. It shouldn’t matter, unless your server is not responding allowing an X-Requested-With header, since you are sending a custom header anyway which will always trigger preflight.

Comment: I've tried both empty string vs null. Same result. I realize the custom header 'X-AUTH' is triggering a preflight, but the jquery request passes the preflight.

Comment: Note that this request will be preflighted even without the X-Requested-With header due to the Content-Type.

Comment: Right, but since I have to send a token (the 'X-AUTH' header) I have no choice. I do the same in the jQuery example.

Comment: Yes, for your getSecure call, that X-AUTH header will also force a preflight.  Please post the request & response headers according to a proxy.

Comment: I've added them in a reply to you above.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar experience with dojo.xhrGet, and 'Content-Type': 'application/json' was the problem.  I had to change it to pretend I was getting back plain text for it to actually work cross domain, thus:

```
dojo.xhrGet({
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': null,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    },
    load: function(responseText) {
        var results = JSON.parse(responseText);
    ...
    }
});
```

After that it worked cross domain, and it treated results as a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

```
          var syncCall = true;
          if(dojo.isFF)
            syncCall = false;
          xhr(url, { 
            method : 'GET',
            handleAs : 'json',
            withCredentials : true,
            sync  :  syncCall,
            headers : {
              'X-XSRF-Token' : settings.XSRF_TOKEN,
              'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use dojo/request/xhr module to make any HTTP request like OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, PUT, HEAD, TRACE etc.

Pass http method name as a string (all in capitals) as below,

```
require(['dojo/request/xhr'], function(xhr){
    xhr(url, {
        handleAs : "json",
        method : 'OPTIONS',
        data : formDataAsJson,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(
        function(data) {
            console.log("response data is: "+ JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        function(err) {
            console.log("The err is: "+ JSON.stringify(err));
        },
        function(evt) {
            console.log("The evt is: "+ JSON.stringify(evt));
        }
    );
});
```